# Auto-populate lookup field works using onchange event but doesn't get selected

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, force.com-sites, bootstrap

I have a Visualforce page where I have a lookup field `Cleaning_Company__c`. The Visualforce page is present inside a force.com site. I want this field to get automatically populated once the password is inputted. The issue is it is getting populated but required me to click on the lookup icon again for the value to get cemented in the field. How can it automatically get selected without clicking on the lookup icon? I have been breaking my head on this for the whole day. Appreciate it if anyone could help.

**VF Code:**

```
<apex:page controller="i2" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true" docType="html-5.0">
<html >

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
              crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Test Form</title>
        <style>
            /* lookup field override */
            .lookupInput a {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            }
            .lookupInput img {
            float: right;
            }
            span.lookupInput {
            position: relative;
            display: inherit;
            }
            .lookupInput a {
            border: none !important;
            background: none !important;
            }
            .move-left {
            width: 18px;
            box-shadow: none;
            }
            /* end lookup field override */

        </style>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <apex:form id="form">

            <apex:outputPanel id="errmsg">
                <apex:pageMessages />
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <form>
                <div class="container" >
                    <h3>
                        Login
                    </h3>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="Password">Password</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Password__c}" styleClass="form-control" >
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!assignPassword}"  reRender="Cleaning,something"  />
                            </apex:inputField>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div align = "center">
                        <apex:commandButton style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(108, 117, 125); border-color:rgb(108, 117, 125) ;user-select: none; background-image: none; border: 1px solid ; border-radius: .25rem; display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.42857143; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;" 
                                            value="Retrieve Cleaning Activities" action="{!retrieve}"  /> 
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <!-- Section -->
                <div class="container">
                    <h3>
                        Cleaning Activity
                    </h3>

                    <br/>


                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="cleaningcompany">Cleaning Company</label>
                            <apex:inputField id="Cleaning" value="{!cle.Cleaning_Company__c}" styleClass="form-control"   />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="operation">Operation Name</label>
                            <apex:inputField id="something" value="{!cle.Operation__c}" styleClass="form-control" required="false" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">PTW Number</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.PTW_Number__c}" styleClass="form-control" required = "false"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Water Usage (in litres)
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Water_Usage_in_litres__c}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Cleaning Start Date</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Start_Time__c}" type="time" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Cleaning End Date
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.End_Time__c}" type="time" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Full Site Cleaning?</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Full_Site_Cleaning__c}"  styleClass="form-control move-left" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Specific Size Cleaned (kWp)
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Specific_Size_Cleaned_kWp__c}"  styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Cleaning Start Date</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Status__c}"  styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Cleaning End Date
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.URL_of_Photos_folder__c}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Start Time</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Date_of_Cleaning__c}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">End Time
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Cleaning_End_Date__c}"  styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Number of Workers</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Number_of_Workers__c}"  styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Hours to Deduct
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!cle.Hours_to_Deduct__c}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(108, 117, 125); border-color:rgb(108, 117, 125) ;user-select: none; background-image: none; border: 1px solid ; border-radius: .25rem; display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.42857143; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;" value="Save Cleaning Activity" action="{!save1}"  >
                            <apex:param name="buttonId1" value="button1" assignTo="{!paramValue}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br/>

                <div class="container">
                    <h3>
                        Permit to Work Number
                    </h3>

                    <br/>


                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Cleaning Activity</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.Cleaning_Activity__c}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">PTW Number
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.PTW_Number1__c}" styleClass="form-control" required="false" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Number of Workers</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.Number_of_Workers__c}" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Date
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.Date__c}" type="date" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Start Time</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.Start_Time__c}" type="time" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">End Time
                            </label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.End_Time__c}" type="time" styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Hours to Deduct</label>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ptw.Hours_to_Deduct__c}"  styleClass="form-control" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <apex:commandButton style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(108, 117, 125); border-color:rgb(108, 117, 125) ;user-select: none; background-image: none; border: 1px solid ; border-radius: .25rem; display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.42857143; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;" value="Save Permit to Work Number" action="{!save1}" reRender="errmsg">

                            <apex:param name="buttonId2" value="button2" assignTo="{!paramValue}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>

                        <apex:commandButton style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(108, 117, 125); border-color:rgb(108, 117, 125) ;user-select: none; background-image: none; border: 1px solid ; border-radius: .25rem; display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.42857143; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;" value="Reset PTW" action="{!refresh}" />

                    </div>
                </div><br/>

                <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" > 
                    <div align="center">

                        <apex:commandbutton value="Update" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand" action="{!saveInlineEdit}"/>

                    </div>


                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!clelist}" var="a" id="tableBlock" style="width:130%" rendered="true">
                        <apex:column headerValue="Ticket Number">
                            <apex:outputLink value="https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/Record_detail_Vf_Page?id = {a.Cleaning_Activity__c}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Contractor">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Cleaning_Company__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Number of Workers">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Number_of_Workers__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Operation Name" value="{!a.Operation__c}"/>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Start Date" value="{!a.Date_of_Cleaning__c}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="End Date" value="{!a.Cleaning_End_Date__c}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="PTW Number" value="{!a.Permit_to_Work_Number__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable> 


                </apex:pageBlock> 






                <!-- Use Button For Submitting Form -->

            </form>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class i2{
    public Cleaning_Activity__c cle{get;set;}
    public Permit_to_Work_Number__c ptw{get;set;}
    public List<Cleaning_Activity__c> clelist{get;set;}
    public String paramValue{get;set;}
    public String errorMessage{get;set;}


    //constructor to create a new record
    public i2(){
        cle = new Cleaning_Activity__c();
        ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c();  

    }

    public void refresh(){
        ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c(); 
        cle = new Cleaning_Activity__c();
    }

    public void init(){
        clelist =  [SELECT Id,Name, Operation__c, Password__c, Cleaning_Company__c, Number_of_Workers__c, Date_of_Cleaning__c, 
                       Cleaning_End_Date__c, Permit_to_Work_Number__c,PTW_Number__c FROM Cleaning_Activity__c where Cleaning_Company__c =: cle.Password__c];
    }

    public PageReference saveInlineEdit() {
      try{ 
            update clelist;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Cleaning Activity is updated'));
        }
        catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
        init();
        return null;

}

    //Assigning password to Cleaning Company
    public void assignPassword(){
        system.debug(cle.Password__c);
        if(cle.Password__c != null){
            cle.Cleaning_Company__c = cle.Password__c;
        }}

    public void retrieve()
    {
        if(cle.Password__c == '0012800001SrXhuAAF' || cle.Password__c == '0011m000006ghzOAAQ')
        {
            clelist = [SELECT Name, Operation__c, Password__c, Cleaning_Company__c, Number_of_Workers__c, Date_of_Cleaning__c, 
                       Cleaning_End_Date__c, Permit_to_Work_Number__c,PTW_Number__c FROM Cleaning_Activity__c where Cleaning_Company__c =: cle.Password__c];
            system.debug(clelist);   
        }
        else if(cle.Password__c == NULL)
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please key in the password to retreive the details'));
        else
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Password is incorrect'));
    }



    public void save1(){  
        system.debug('paramValue ' + paramValue);
        if(paramValue == 'button2')
        {
            system.debug('Password is ' + cle.Password__c);
            if(cle.Password__c == '0012800001SrXhuAAF' || cle.Password__c == '0011m000006ghzOAAQ') 
            {
                if(ptw.Cleaning_Activity__c != NULL)
                {
                    System.debug('I am here');
                    upsert ptw;
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'PTW Inserted Successfully'));
                    ptw = new Permit_to_Work_Number__c();
                }
                else
                    {

                        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please input the Cleaning Activity to save Permit to Work Number'));  
                    }

            }
                else
                {
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Wrong Password'));
                }

            }
            else
            {

                if(cle.Password__c == '0012800001SrXhuAAF' || cle.Password__c == '0011m000006ghzOAAQ')
                { 
                    if(cle.Operation__c != NULL)
                    {
                        upsert cle;
                        clelist = [SELECT Name, Operation__c, Cleaning_Company__c, Password__c, Date_of_Cleaning__c,
                                   Cleaning_End_Date__c,Number_of_Workers__c,
                                   Permit_to_Work_Number__c FROM Cleaning_Activity__c where Password__c =: cle.Password__c];
                        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Cleaning Activity Inserted Successfully'));
                        system.debug(clelist);
                        cle = new Cleaning_Activity__c();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorMessage = 'Operations is required';
                        //ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please input the Operation Name'));  
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Wrong Password'));
                }
            }



        }



    }
```

**Lookup is populated but not selected**

[image: Lookup is populated but not selected]

**Edit 1:** As you can see below the value is now selected. Unlike the previous image where you don't have "click the look up icon" placeholder

[image]

Comment: What do you mean cemented in? What in particular is not working as a result of your issue? You say it does not get selected but I am not sure how you mean exactly.

Comment: @ZachHutchins What I mean is that the lookup populates with the value but it is not selected properly. Only when I use the lookup and select the same value it is getting cemented. Please see mu edit 1 to understand better. Are you able to suggest a workaround to fix the issue? If you need more details, let me know and I will add it to the post.

Comment: Im not exactly sure how you have bits that are related to classic style sheets and parts that are related to lightning style sheets. Also when I created a small test doing roughly what you are doing I don't get that "Click lookup Icon..." though when i use classic or lightning style sheets. my guess is it has something to do with the overrides you are using there, it looks like you are just using bootstrap for form alignment. Workaround could be you just hide that what looks like a span using css if you can select it with a class, or alternativly you could onComplete run some js to remove it.

Comment: I had figured it out. Wrapping ```<apex:inputField>``` inside ```<apex:outputPanel>``` with reRender did the trick.